# Animated GIF transparency waves In Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, animation

I created an animated outer glow around a shape like shown below:

[image]

But when I save it the outer glow shape changes to dotted instead of clear glow.

Comment: The issue you have there is the file format. In gif transparency is either on or off. There's nothing in between. So realistically you can't save a gif (animated or not) with translucency if you're expecting it to stay that way. It'll always get the matte background color, which can actually work in some situations where you can match the matte color to the background color of where the gif is used.